# Excel Macro Ignoring a step to change column size of A and G

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried everything I can think of to make this work, I have put it in multiple sections of the macro to no avail...

```
 For Each Current In Worksheets
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 9.29
Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 13.75
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Append the worksheet to the range or it will only use the active sheet:

```
 For Each Current In Worksheets

    Current.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 9.29
    Current.Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 13.75

Next
```